# Шаблонизатор

Tags: шаблонизаторы

Здраствуйте. У меня есть вопрос, связаный с шаблонизтором. А точнее с тем, какой взять шаблонизатор, что б в нем были данные функции:

- Замена {...} на то, что я укажу в функции
- Самое главное: возможность ставить ссылки типа: href= и тут должен как то открыватся шаблон который я укажу в скобках

А также я хочу посмотреть примеры, особенно 2 пункта, ибо шаблонизаторов - куча, но как реализовать - фиг поймешь. Шаблонизаторы в которых 3+ файла не предлагать, ибо мне нужен супер простой шаблонизатор для удобности а не супер гипер сайта. Заранее спасибо!

UPD1: Я хотел бы использовать шаблонизатор DLE, или даже сам DLE, но выходил трабл, ругается Fatal Error'ом на eval

Comment: Спасибо, но это у меня уже есть. Мне бы хотелось второй пункт) А так  спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По первому пункту

```
function render($text, array $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $var) {
        $l = strlen($key);
        $isValidKey = $l > 0 && $key[0] === '{' && $key[$l - 1] === '}';
        if (is_callable($var)) {
            $var = call_user_func($var);
        }
        $isValidEntry = is_string($var);
        if (!$isValidKey) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Invalid key: ['.$key.']. Key has to be a string beginning and ending with a curly brace.');
        }
        if (!$isValidEntry) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Invalid entry stored under key ['.$key.']. Entry has to be a string or a returning string callable.');
        }
        $text = str_replace($key, $var, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Работает?

```
$callable = function() {
    return 'Would you kindly not open until Would you kindly not open until 63° 2° N, 29° 55° W.';
};
$text = 'I am a {templateName} template. This is output from callable: {callableOutput}.';
echo render($text, array('{templateName}' => 'dummy', '{callableOutput}' => $callable));
```

Работает:

> I am a dummy template. This is output from callable: Would you kindly not open until 63° 2° N, 29° 55° W.